# Como preencher varios campos input com dados vindos do banco de dados?

Tags: javascript, java, aplicação-web, play-framework

Estou com um probleminha no meu sistema, ja cadastrei varios equipamentos no meu sistema, porem cada equipamento tem uma lista de portas.

---

Como faço pra gerar inputs dinamicamente de acordo com a quantidade de portas cadastradas no banco?

---

> **Exemplo:** equipamento **X** tem 5 portas, nessa tela gera-se dinamicamente os 5 campos inputs com as 5 descrições de portas vindas do banco, para que o usuário possa ter a opção de editar essas informações. 
>   Como estou fazendo, ele ta gerando apenas um campo com um array de valores.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<input type="hidden" name="patchpanel.id" value="${p?.id}" />
<label>Portas:</label> 
    <input type="text" name="patchpanel.portas.descricao" 
           class="form-control"
           value="${flash['patchpanel.portas.descricao'] 
                    ? flash['patchpanel.portas.descricao'] 
                    : p?.portas.descricao}" />
```

Meu model `patchpanel`

```
@Entity
public class Patchpanel extends Model {

@Required 
public String nome; 
@Required 
public String mac; 
@Required 
@IPv4Address 
public String ip; 
@Required 
public String numPortas; 

@OneToMany(
    cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}, 
    mappedBy="patchpanel") 
public List<Porta> portas; 

@ManyToOne 
@JoinColumn(name="torre_id") 
public Torre torre; 

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING) 
public Status status;
```

Meu model portas:

```
@Entity
public class Porta extends Model {

@Required
public String descricao;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
public Status status;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
public StatusEquipamento statusEquipamento;
```

Creio que seria usando jquery, mas nao sei implementar pois nao domino ainda essa linguagem.

Comment: Como você está conversando com o banco? PHP?

Comment: tdo java, usando o framework play